# support vector machines for classifying images

Tags: python, svm

I am trying to use SVMs to classify a set if images I have on my computer into 3 categories :

I am just facing a problem of how to load the data as in the following example , he uses a data set that is already saved. 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_digits_classification.html

Me I have all the images in png format saved in a folder on my pc

Answer (score 0):

You can load data as numpy arrays using Pillow, in this way:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

data = np.array(Image.open('yourimg.png')) # .astype(float) if necessary
```

couple it with [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) to read multiple files, e.g.

```
import os
for file in os.listdir('your_dir/'):
    img = Image.open(os.path.join('your_dir/', file))
    data = np.array(img)
    your_model.train(data)
```

Comment: But this will read only one image ,I would like to read all the images in the folder